# Share a directory over FTP with chroot_local enabled

Tags: directory, ftp, chroot, vsftpd

I'm using vsftpd. By default, when I create a user, they are jailed in their directory which is `/home/user`.
I have enabled `chroot_local_user=YES`.

On the other hand, I also wanted to create a shared directory for all the FTP users. so in a nutshell, they have their own directory and they have a shared group folder

```
/
+/home
   +user1
   +shared_folder
```

How can I give the users access to the shared directory over FTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to "mount --bind" the shared directory into the user's directory.

```
mount --bind /home/actual_share/ /home/someguy/shared/
```

I assume you'll need to add group write to the "actual_share".

Got the idea from [this forum post](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=133937).

Comment: @user1666411 -- put the "shared" folder in each user's chroot / home. So if I have two users, bob and betty, I have /home/bob/shared & /home/betty/shared and then the "base" share if you will @ /home/share/ -- then do a `mount --bind /home/share /home/user/shared` for each user<BR/>

Comment: You're welcome, btw!! Glad it worked out :)